# Make iOS 7 Safari open PDF that is forced in other browsers

Tags: c#, pdf, ios7, force-download

I have looked around on stackowerflow and i cant find the answer i'm looking for so here is my problem.

I'm building a application that is forcing download of a pdf on every browser and the application is creating this pdf by geting values from a server so a direct link is not the answer.

This is my code:

```
    private bool SendPDF(string geoCode, string period)
    {
        bool result = false;
        using (var db = new prerenderedreportsDataContext())
        {

            var q = (from r in db.RenderedReports where r.GeographicCode == geoCode && r.Period == period select r).SingleOrDefault();

            if (q != null && q.ReportPDF != null)
            {
                byte[] data = q.ReportPDF.ToArray();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream .pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"landfaktablad_" + geoCode + "_" + period + ".pdf\"");
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length:", data.Length.ToString());
                Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "Binary");
                Response.BinaryWrite(data);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I understand that iOS 7 doesen't support downloading so how can i get safari views the pdf instead of try to downloading it. Now it works on previous iOS and IE etc but iOS safari crashes.

Someone how have a solution?

Comment: Found the answer so if someone have the same problem sometime i fixed it by adding this code instead.

byte[] data= GetFoo();
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", @"attachment;filename=""MyFile.pdf""");
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";            
Response.BinaryWrite(data);
Response.End();